# Finding unique pairs in lottery tickets

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics

I was trying to solve one of the [hackerrank practice questions](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:__1NxNxe7D4J:https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/winning-lottery-ticket+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de). Could anyone please let me know how can I make this code much effective, in terms of time and space complexity?

> The Super Bowl Lottery is about to commence, and there are several
>   lottery tickets being sold, and each ticket is identified with a
>   ticket ID. In one of the many winning scenarios in the Superbowl
>   lottery, a winning pair of tickets is:
>
> - Concatenation of the two ticket IDs in the pair, in any order,
>     contains each digit from *0* to *9* at least once.
>
> For example, if there are *2* distinct tickets with ticket ID *12930455* and 56789, (*129300455*, *56789*) is a winning pair.
>
> NOTE: The ticket IDs can be concantenated in any order. Digits in the
>   ticket ID can occur in any order.
>
> Your task is to find the number of winning pairs of distinct tickets,
>   such that concatenation of their ticket IDs (in any order) makes for a
>   winning scenario. Complete the function `winningLotteryTicket` which
>   takes a string array of ticket IDs as input, and return the number of
>   winning pairs.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains *n* denoting the total number of lottery tickets
>   in the Super Bowl. Each of the next *n* lines contains a string, where
>   string on a *i*<sup>th</sup> line denotes the ticket id of the *i*<sup>th</sup> ticket.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - [1 ≤ pretty much everything  input ≤ 10⁶]
> - Each ticket id consists of digits from [*0*, *9*]
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the number of pairs in a new line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 5  
> 129300455  
> 5559948277  
> 012334556  
> 56789  
> 123456879
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> 5
> ```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
    static Long winningLotteryTicket(String[] tickets) {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tickets.length-1 ; i++) {
            for(int j = i+1 ; j < tickets.length ;j++ ){
               if(!(tickets[i]).equals(tickets[j]) && getStatus(tickets[i],tickets[j])){
                   count++;
               }
            }
        }
        return Long.valueOf(count);
    }

    public static boolean getStatus(String a, String b){
        String c = a+b;
        if(c.length() < 10){
            return false;
        }
        Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
        char[] arr = c.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            charSet.add(arr[i]);
        }

        if (charSet.size() == 10){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String[] tickets = new String[n];
        for(int tickets_i = 0; tickets_i < n; tickets_i++){
            tickets[tickets_i] = in.next();
        }
        Long result = winningLotteryTicket(tickets);
        System.out.println(result);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The words "from to at" from the task description don't make any sense to me. Could you re-check the whole description? It seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Oh, and you could fix the indentation of the code so that the review can concentrate on more interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

#### `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, you can use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource.

#### `return boolean`

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

This kind of code can be simplified as `return condition`.

#### Method names

Your naming can be better refined to reflect what they are doing. For example, `getStatus` can be renamed as `hasUniqueNumerals`, following the standard `is/has` prefix for methods returning a `boolean`. `winningLotteryTicket` can be renamed as `countWinningPairs`.

#### `for-each` loop

Your loop on `c.toCharArray()` can also be written as:

```
for (char current : c.toCharArray()) {
    charSet.add(current);
}
```

#### What's nice

- You checked if the concatenation of the two inputs will give you 10 or more digits, returning `false` first if not.
- You declared `charSet` as a `Set` rather than a `HashSet` and relied on generic type inference.

Answer (score 0):

Listless additions to [h.j.k.'s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/186252/93149):

- no [doc comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide)
- the name `getStatus()` is not hinting in a useful direction
- the number of winning pairs may easily exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
  (there may have been a reason for `Long`)

code alternative for `getStatus()` without concatenation, with one more *early out*:

```
/** Adds <code>char</code>s from <code>a</code> to <code>charSet</code>
 * @return size of the resulting <code>Set&lt;Character></code> */
static int accumulateChars(Set<Character> charSet, String a) {
    for (char c: a.toCharArray())
        charSet.add(c);
    return charSet.size();
}

static boolean all10(final String a, final String b) {
    if (a.length()+b.length() < 10)
        return false;
    final Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<>();
    return accumulateChars(charSet, a) <= 10
        && 10 == accumulateChars(charSet, b);
}
```

In each iteration of `winningLotteryTicket()`'s outer loop, `tickets[i]` stays the same for all the iterations of the inner loop, as does its contribution to *the set*.
If you didn't literally concatenate strings, it was apparent that the same sets were created for the 2nd ticket's digits time and again - and the sets "checked for completeness" were the unions of the digit/char sets of tickets *i* and *j*:
It looks advantageous to create each ticket's set once and for all and think hard about what can be done to reduce the number of set unions to evaluate - if ticket *i* consists of 2 distinct digits, only, there's no need to pair with any ticket consisting of no more than 7 distinct digits.
If one ticket contains every digit, it is a winner paired with every other ticket …

If and when coding that *proves* not fast enough, note that the digit sets are quite small and reconsider their representation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [greybeard’s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/190888/120114):

> "same sets were created for the 2nd ticket's digits time and again - and the sets "checked for completeness" were the unions of the digit/char sets of tickets i and j:"

giving every individual a winning opportunity opposed to having one number match for two tickets would nearly be impossible or would take years to win it finding that matching ticket.